# how to stop mainloop function without closing window

Tags: python, debugging, tkinter

I want to debug my program and i want to freeze the window by stopping mainloop but without closing the window.

I tried to use `quit()` and `destroy()` but both just close the window.
A little example of part of my code:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
root=Tk()
root.bind('<Space>', lambda e: '<------what to put here')
```

Can I close mainloop without the window always closing so that it can freeze and i can look at it closely. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`quit` won't destroy the window. However, it might cause your program to stop if you have no code to prevent it from stopping after `mainloop` returns.

If all you want to do is have it freeze for debugging purposes, there is no need to stop `mainloop`. The simplest method is to start the pdb debugger which will give you a prompt and prevent the mainloop from processing events until you exit pdb.

```
def pause(event=None):
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()

root.bind('<Space>', pause)
```

Of course, you don't have to use `pdb` here - any function which doesn't return will work. For example, you could call `input` or `read`. `pdb` is convenient because it makes it possible to examine variables, run other code, or step through the program one line at a time.

If you literally want to "close mainloop", call the `quit` method. That is literally what it does -- it tells `mainloop` to quit. You're responsible for adding code after `mainloop` returns to prevent the window from closing.

Comment: i realized it doesn't freeze it just makes that after my program is finished it spams me with (pdb) even control + c doesn't stop it i need to close and reopen the window

Comment: @chboo1: I don't understand your comment. When you call `pdb.set_trace()` it does exactly what you want - it pauses the GUI. You can then type commands at the pdb prompt. When you exit pdb, the program continues.